# CSS display:table; spacing issue on Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm using `display:table;` on a `div`element.
On all other browsers I've tested there are no issues.
However, on Chrome 22 (latest) and Canary, the `div` receives 1px spacing on both left and right sides.

Any idea where the problem lays?

**EDIT:**
`margin`,`border`,`padding` are all 0.

Also, any table properties are removed:

```
border-spacing:0;
border-collapse:collapse;
table-layout:fixed;
```

Comment: Any fiddles? Are you resetting all the elements using reset.css or any of that sort. If not I recommend using one.

Comment: Do you mean 1px padding or margin? As above I'd recommend trying a reset.css file.

Comment: Thing is, it's neither. Padding is 0, margin is 0, border is 0. Then border-spacing:0;border-collapse:collapse;table-layout:fixed;.

Comment: Can you set the div to have a `margin: 0 -1px`?

Comment: I could, but that would affect other browsers which act normally.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem. It was caused by Micro clearfix hack. Removed the .clearfix style solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I would also look at whitespace as a possible offender and test with `font-size: 0`.

Comment: That's a good idea. I'll give that a shot next week. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would reset the margin and padding on all browsers.

```
*{margin:0; padding:0;}
```

Note you can also download a reset css file if you want also.

[normalize.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/) or [reset.css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2011/01/03/reset-revisited/)

Comment: I've edited my answer. It's not margins or paddings. It's a browser quirk I'd say.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from this question solved my issue: [CSS Table Cell In Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571612/css-table-cell-in-chrome)

They recommend adding `table-layout: fixed` to the element where you've applied `display: table`.

If your markup doesn't have the `.clearfix` hack applied, as was my case, this might help you!

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed this issue back in 2015 - it's only affecting google chrome and the only way to fix it is to move your display:table to a child container, so if you have:

```
<div style="width:50%; height:300px; display:table">
     <div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
          <p>Your centred content here</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Change it to the following adding one more div:

```
<div style="width:50%;">
     <div style="display:table; height:300px;">
          <div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
               <p>Your centred content here</p>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

It looks like in google chrome there is a conflict with width and display:table when it's applied to the same tag.

Open up the following link in both chrome and firefox and you'll see that the right borders align in firefox but not in chrome because it adds 1px extra gap.

Long story short, my fix works in chrome:)

https://jsfiddle.net/2u1t8ffj/

[image: Firefox on the left - fine, Chrome on the right - 1px gap]