# CSS Table Cell In Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a piece of code that works fine in IE and Firefox. It has 3 table cells inside a display:table; wrapper. The middle cell has a fixed width with a backround image, and the left and right cells have no width and a solid colour. In firefox and ie the left and right columns expand to fill the remaining space, as a table would...but in chrome these two cells are showing no width at all.

I need it to expand the left and right columns to fill the remaining space on the left and right of the centre cell.

CSS

```
#navbar{
    width:100%;
    height:43px;
    border-bottom:2px solid #ffffff;    
    display:table;
}

#navbar #left{
    display:table-cell;
    background:#fcb316;
}

#navbar #middle{
    display:table-cell;
    width:1024px;
    height:43px;
    background:url(images/nav-bg.jpg) no-repeat;
}

#navbar #right{
    display:table-cell;
    background:#8cc63f;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="navbar"> 
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="middle"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: just out of curiosity - why do you need it this way? there might be a simpler way to do what you want

Answer (score 3):

Add `table-layout: fixed;` to `#navbar`.

This fixes the problem because:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#fixed-table-layout

> In the fixed table layout algorithm, the width of each column is
>   determined as follows:
>
> 1. A column element with a value other than 'auto' for the 'width' property sets the width for that column.
> 2. Otherwise, a cell in the first row with a value other than 'auto' for the 'width' property determines the width for that column. If the
>      cell spans more than one column, the width is divided over the
>      columns.
> 3. **Any remaining columns equally divide the remaining horizontal table space (minus borders or cell spacing).**

Comment: nice answer, forgot about this css

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer also had problems with empty element.

Try this:

```
<div id="navbar"> 
    <div id="left">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="middle">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="right">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```